# Redirect to another state when resolving in ui-router in angularJS 1.3.X

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

here is the case: I'd like to redirect to different state based on the status of the resource I resolved in a parent state.

My question is, can I use `$state.go` to interrupt resolving? Will the child states of this state be executed before `$state.go`?

From my experiments, with the sample code, if I send a request to url: `/parentState/default` with a `aResource` status of `A`, it still executed all the resolve functions of these states-chain. Is there a better way to escape from the states chain?

This is the sample code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('PARENT_STATE', {
        url: '/parentState',
        abstact: true,
        resolve: {
            aResource: function($state, RemoteDataService) {
                return RemoteDataService.getItem()
                    .then(function(aResource) {
                        if (aResource.status === 'A') {
                            $state.go('A_CHILD_STATE');
                            return;
                        } else if (aResource.status === 'B') {
                            $state.go('B_CHILD_STATE');
                            return;
                        } else {
                            return aResource;
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    })
    .state('PARENT_STATE.CHILD_STATE_A', {
        url: 'a',
    })
    .state('PARENT_STATE.CHILD_STATE_B', {
        url: 'b'
    })
    .state('PARENT_STATE.DEFAULT_CHILD_STATE', {
        url: 'default',
        resolve: {
            aResource: function() {
                // this line will be executed even if aResource.state === 'A' or 'B'
                // but I hope I can ignore this function in such condition 
            }
        }
    })
})
```